# How to get smooth parallax effect

Tags: javascript, parallax

I created a simple parallax function and I have many elements on the site that use this effect.
I don't understand why such a simple function works so clumsy but the effect is not smooth. I tried different methods of code optimization but there was no change. I'd rather not use libraries. Would using jQuery as a framework give a better effect?

I wonder how the parallax effect is constructed in the ScrollMagic library or on Apple pages. There is a lot more code but it works faster. Maybe because of different way of calculating the offset. Does anybody have an idea?

javascript code

```
  window.onscroll = function() {
  parallax(document.getElementsByClassName("el")[0], 2);
}

function parallax(a, b) {
   a.style.top = Math.round(window.scrollY / b) + "px";
}
```

Comment: have you tried it without the Math.round?

Comment: yes, I did but I believe that it is working faster with it

Comment: hmm I think it's very unlikely that this is is a computational efficiency problem, maybe there is a way to adjust scroll position in a smoother way?  Maybe look into transitions or other ways to set scroll position besides a.style.top.  I'm not too familiar with this but those are the things I'd look at first

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried to use translateY, marginTop, matrix instead of top, but the effect was the same